# Converting DEM (TIFF) files to terrain files?

Tags: dem, terrain, ol-cesium, terrain-tools

I want to create an app to show 3D using [ol-cesium](https://openlayers.org/ol-cesium/). In ol-cesium example it use cesium terrains, But I want to do it with my DEM files.

How can I convert my DEM (TIFF) files to terrain files?

Comment: This library looks promising: https://github.com/geo-data/cesium-terrain-builder

Comment: Then you can publish your solution as an answer to help others with similar problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to generate terrain files i used  [cesium terrain builder](https://github.com/geo-data/cesium-terrain-builder)
if you want to have quick result use docker to simplify generate process.
after generate terrain files i put them on tomcat in test folder and use it:

```
this.map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM()
    })
  ],
  view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
  })
});

const ol3d = new OLCesium({
  map: this.map,
});
const sc = ol3d.getCesiumScene();
const terrainProvider = new Cesium.CesiumTerrainProvider({
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/test'
});
sc.terrainProvider = terrainProvider;
```

but it doesn't work. should i use another way?